# Как сделать динамичные headers для tableview

Tags: ios, swift

Каким образом можно сделать следующее
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть чтобы хэдеры в `tableview` можно было ставить не статично один раз
А чтобы можно было вставить новый хэдер через 3-4 строки

Comment: Приведите пример кода, что пробовали для этого?

Comment: Я ничего не пробовал для этого, так как не знаю как это сделать, поэтому и написал

Comment: Предлагаю заюзать xib кастомный и подгружать тогда, когда вам это не обходимо

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите, чтобы эти хэдеры приклеплялись к верхней части экрана при скролле (как в стиле .grouped UITableView), то делайте несколько секций в таблице, а хэдеры делайте хэдерами секций, и не забудьте сам стиль таблицы поставить в .grouped.

Если же прикрепления не нужно, можно просто сделать ещё один тип ячеек, и использовать вместо хэдеров их.